# Forming Norton generator from a voltage source and two resistors

Tags: circuit-analysis, norton

[image]

Can I combine the **E**,**R** and **Xl** to form a current generator, with **R** and **Xl** in parallel. I need to find the impedance of Z so it develops most power, R-jX, or Z*, if Z is the impedance of the rest of the circuit.

EDIT: That is whether it can be transformed into this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fziFm1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I combine the E,R and Xl to form a current generator,

Yes. Any 1-port linear network, other than an ideal voltage source, can be modeled by a Norton equivalent circuit.

> ... with R and Xl in parallel.

No.

To find the Norton equivalent circuit, you need to find two points along the one-port networks' I-V curve, and then determine the equivalent current source and shunt admittance from that. Typically it's easiest to use the short-circuit output current and open-circuit output voltage as the two points.

Comment: would you look at the edit, not sure if we are on the same page.

Comment: Yes, your edit shows an equivalent circuit for the original. However, it's not really the canonical form for a Norton equivalent. A Norton equivalent should really just have a conductance and a susceptance (the real and imaginary parts of admittance, respectively) in parallel.